# "Unable to locate element" before I click on new browser window

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I try to click on the element with the class name "mat-select-arrow-wrapper.ng-tns-c73-7" on the website below. This causes the error "Unable to locate element" until I click the new browser window once, how can I get around this? The other two boxes to the left of this do not exhibit the problem.

My code currently looks like this:

```
url = "https://www.pamyra.de/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_class_name("mat-select-arrow-wrapper.ng-tns-c73-7").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have css selector `.mat-select-arrow-wrapper.ng-tns-c73-7` and you are causing `by_class_name` is the reason why you are getting the exception.

Please use below code :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".mat-select-arrow-wrapper.ng-tns-c73-7").click()
```

**Full code should look like this :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()

url = "https://www.pamyra.de/"

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".mat-select-arrow-wrapper.ng-tns-c73-7").click()
```

**Update 1 :**

**With Explicit waits :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

url = "https://www.pamyra.de/"

driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#mat-select-value-5+div"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still get the following error message: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".mat-select-arrow-wrapper.ng-tns-c73-7"}
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81). It works like before if I click in the browser window

Comment: Please try now, have added `driver.implicitly_wait(30)`

Comment: Unfortunately still the same error

Comment: That is strange, it did work in my local. Let me give a solution with explicit waits

Comment: Please see above.

Comment: Thank you! I found out that it works alwalys only the first time after I restart my kernel, what could be the reason for this?

Comment: UPDATE Not always, only sometimes, sometimes I get time run out error

Comment: There isn't much you can do within selenium. That probably could be cause webapp is detecting your script as a malicious bot.